# Why does Russia have multiple deputy prime ministers?

Tags: russian-federation

- [Deputy Prime Minister of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deputy_Prime_Minister_of_Russia)

Why does Russia have multiple deputy prime ministers?

I mean, in other countries, they generally have one prime minister, some ministers, and under ministers, they have state ministers or deputy ministers.

- [Government of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_Russia#Lists_of_ministers)

I see that Russia also has ministers.

So, what is the explanation?

Comment: I don´t think there will be an objective ansver, the prime minister can decide how many deputies he has. The previous one had even more deputies.

Comment: Lots of country of multiple deputy prime ministers, and keep in mind that job titles like this, in translation, may not have exactly the same connotations as they do in the original language.

Answer (score 4):

A leader of a modern country with tens of millions of citizens or more has to be a bit of a jack of all trades but expert of none (or perhaps an expert of a small number of specialties). Most modern countries' governments are explicitly set up so as to have people lead branches of the executive who are (a) experts in a certain topic and (b) have the same political leanings as does the leader of the country. In Russia, these people are called deputy prime ministers. In Great Britain, they're called [cabinet ministers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_(government)). In the US, they're called secretaries, directors, or some other title. (The US [Secretary of Defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Secretary_of_Defense) is not the kind of secretary that you might ask to fetch you a cup of coffee.)

The concept is the same; it's only the titles that differ. The leader of a modern large country cannot possibly do the entire job of keeping that country going, and the leader will inevitably want those top expert positions to be filled with people who know what they're doing and who agree (more or less) with the leader of the country. In Russia, these key positions are informally categorized as Deputy Prime Ministers.

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question. Russia also has ministers, their MoD is the correspondent to the sec Def etc.) It might actually be a Russian or Soviet tradition to have a lot of deputy positions, across the board. Even their Duma (parliamentary) committee for defense had like four or five deputy chairmen.

Comment: "experts in a certain topic": in the UK (and presumably other parliamentary states), ministers in general are not required to have any expertise in their subjects, and mostly don't. It's the job of civil servants to provide that expertise.

Comment: In the UK, most political heads of department have the title [Secretary of State for <dept>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_of_State_(United_Kingdom)), commonly referred to as <dept> Secretary. All of them are ministers and are in the cabinet, but the PM may also choose to invite other (non-SoS) ministers at his discretion.